# exscript ssh on python

Tags: ssh, command, paramiko

Im having problem with the exscript, i want to ssh to my cisco switches, but im having some trouble

I wrote 2 scripts,

with this one I dont have any problem, I can change the default gateway just by running the script and entering the user and password:

---

```
from Exscript.util.interact import read_login
from Exscript.protocols import SSH2

account = read_login()
enter code here`conn = SSH2()
conn.connect('192.168.86.12')
conn.login(account)
conn.execute('conf t')
conn.execute('no ip default-gateway')
conn.execute('ip default-gateway 192.168.68.10')

print "Response was:", repr(conn.response)
conn.send('exit\r')
conn.close()
```

---

But the problem comes here. I want to make it automatic, I dont want to enter the user and password by hand.
So I wrote this script,

---

```
from Exscript.util.interact import read_login
from Exscript.protocols import SSH2

#account = read_login()
conn = SSH2()
conn.connect('192.168.86.12')
conn.login('user','password')
conn.execute('conf t')
conn.execute('no ip default-gateway')
conn.execute('ip default-gateway 192.168.68.10')

print "Response was:", repr(conn.response)
conn.send('exit\r')
conn.close()
```

---

But it gives me this error output..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "nn.py", line 7, in <module>
conn.login('user','password')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Exscript-DEVELOPMENT-py2.7.egg/Exscript/protocols/Protocol.py", line 591, in login
with self._get_account(account) as account:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Exscript-DEVELOPMENT-py2.7.egg/Exscript/protocols/Protocol.py", line 567, in _get_account
account.__enter__()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__enter__'
```

ps: I have tried also with paramiko, but it doesnt allow me to run multiple commands.

Answer (score 3):

The login function expects an `Exscript.Account` object. Load your username and password into an `Account` and pass that in.

```
from Exscript.protocols import SSH2
from Exscript import Account

account = Account('user', 'password')
conn = SSH2()
conn.connect('192.168.86.12')
conn.login(account)
# ...
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from Exscript.util.interact import read_login
from Exscript.protocols import SSH2
from Exscript import Host, Account

account1 = Account('uname','pwd')
conn = SSH2()
conn.connect('192.168.86.12')
conn.login(account1)
conn.execute('conf t')
conn.execute('no ip default-gateway')
conn.execute('ip default-gateway 192.168.68.10')

print "Response was:", repr(conn.response)
conn.send('exit\r')
conn.close()
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to have some explanation as to what the changes are that you made and why it works/should be that way.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Its just the Host and Account module that needed to be imported.

Answer (score 0):

I am new in this stuff and getting lot of hard time in my job,hope you guys help in this.

While login in multi nodes insert a certain commands to reconfirm the status of links and this should be document in a "txt" file or "log" file for confirmation
I reached till below

```
from Exscript.protocols import SSH2    
from Exscript.util.file import get_hosts_from_file    
from Exscript import Account

accounts = [Account('myuser', 'mypassword')]    
conn = SSH2()          
hosts = get_hosts_from_file('myhosts.txt') 

def do_something(job, host, conn):
    conn.execute('sh int description | i PE')

start(hosts, accounts, do_something)    
conn.send('exit\r')    
conn.close()
```